How to fix "No static resource" found error, and use dynamic resources instead (404 Error)
Trying to use Spring endpoints, but it is not making any sense. I keep getting an error
2024-05-15T11:56:44.452-04:00 DEBUG 14324 --- [test-engine] [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2024-05-15T11:56:44.455-04:00 DEBUG 14324 --- [test-engine] [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2024-05-15T11:56:44.456-04:00 DEBUG 14324 --- [test-engine] [nio-8080-exec-5] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource TestEngine/batch.]
2024-05-15T11:56:44.456-04:00 DEBUG 14324 --- [test-engine] [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND

I feel like I must be missing somethin in the code.
-- application.properties --
#Server
server.servlet.context-path=/TestEngine

-- Controller --
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ManagementService {
    
    
    
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,
            value = "batch", 
            produces = MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity getDetails() {        
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("Test");
    }
    
}

-- pom/xml --
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>

-- main --
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "controllers")
public class AoeEngineApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestEngineApplication.class, args);
    }

}


Looking back on this I am not sure what the exact issue was, but I solve these type of issue by just adding scan packages. I suspect that is what I was missing this time also.

Not only might you need to scan anywhere in your app, sometimes you have to scan packages in various libraries.
